# Где хранятся данные, отправляемые с помощью input

Tags: html5

Всем привет! Такой вопрос: где хранятся данные (логин пароль), которые отправляются при нажатии на кнопку submit? (на сервер не отправляю, вопрос именно про то, где они хранятся на моем компьютере) Код прилагаю:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan = "2"> Аутентификация </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center> Логин: </center></td>
        <td> <input type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center> Пароль:</center> </td>
        <td><center> <input type="password" /></center> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "2"> <center> <input type="submit" value="Вход" /> </center> </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: на компьютере - нигде )))

Comment: Они хранятся там, куда вы их сохранили

Comment: @humster_spb, препод говорит, что ответ неправильный

Comment: _где хранятся данные (логин пароль), которые отправляются при нажатии на кнопку submit_ - если что-то ввести, то данные "хранятся" в атрибуте эл-та (в любом случае, абсолютно любые данные "хранятся" в памяти пк); но, вообще, вопрос некорректный и бессмысленный

Comment: В зависимости от учебного заведения и преподавателя, ожидаемым ответом может быть "в операвтиной памяти компьютера", "в памяти процесса браузера",  "в куках" - и ни один из этих ответов не является правильным, потому что вопрос неправильный

Comment: Можно предположить, что Ваш препод имеет в виду get-запрос. Действительно, данные МОГУТ передаваться в адресную строку в качестве параметров get-запроса после нажатия на submit. Но для этого форме надо добавить атрибут method со значением get, а полям формы - атрибуты name.